# Can I remove the need for the double lambda in this generic expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, extension-methods

I've made this extension method (I know right now there's no exception checking etc, will be added once I'm sure the function is actually correct):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> ChangeProperty<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,Expression<Func<TSource,TResult>> res, Func<TSource, TResult> changeProp)
    {
        Type type = typeof(TSource);
        MemberExpression member = res.Body as MemberExpression;
        var name = member.Member.Name;

        foreach (var x in source)
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(name);
            prop.SetValue(x, changeProp(x));
            Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(x));
        }
        return source;
    }
```

And is used in this context(Remove unwanted tags strips html tags out of a string):

```
_dc.EmailTemplates
.ChangeProperty(x=>x.Body,z=>RemoveUnwantedTags(z.Body))
.ToList();
```

But I don't like that I have to use a double lambda, one for getting the property name, and then one for executing the function. I don't know if it's my lack of understanding on how Expression<> works, or if im missing something really obvious but would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to just do `foreach (var x in ...) x.Body = RemoveUnwantedTags(x.Body); }` or similar? No need for the reflection, lambdas, etc

Comment: I agree with @canton7, but I'm also aware that lambdas are mainstream at the moment..

Comment: If you *really* want, you could define e.g. a `Tap` method, and do `_dc.EmailTemplates.Tap(x => x.Body = RemoveUnwantedTags(x.Body)).ToList()`, but that's starting to smell a bit, and might bite due to Linq's lazy nature

Comment: (Also, put the `type.GetProperty(name)` *above* the `foreach` loop - it's very expensive, relatively, and doesn't depend on `x`.)

Comment: @canton7 I wanted a generic function that can replace any property of an object in a collection using a method of the same return type, I have a lot of database reads where the data needs sanitized or generated, and rather than putting a foreach on every one I wanted a way to just bundle it into the same linq query that gets the data. I know it would be easier using a foreach though

Comment: Then consider something like the `Tap` method I described above. Surely `c.SomeMethod(x => x.Body = RemoveUnwantedTags(x.Body))` is better than `c.SomeMethod(x => x.Body, x => RemoveUnwatedTags(x.Body))`?

Comment: @i.Dio: Lambdas aren't so mainstream that you're now compelled to obfuscate your code with them.

Comment: I do agree that needless lambdas decrease readability in some cases, but I have a lot of different objects that all require just one property to be changed, this saves me making loads of for loops for one change to a collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to how `ForEach` is used in `List<T>` the desired functionality can be simplified to

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Apply<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> action) {
    foreach (var item in source) {
        action(item);
        yield return item;            
    }        
}
```

and used

```
_dc.EmailTemplates
    .Apply(x => x.Body = RemoveUnwantedTags(x.Body))
    .ToList();
```

This can also be used for multiple members by doing

```
_dc.EmailTemplates
    .Apply(x => {
        x.Body = RemoveUnwantedTags(x.Body);
        x.SomeOtherMember = SomeOtherFunction(x.SomeOtherMember);
    })
    .ToList();
```